# httponly cookie not available in javascript. How do I make non-httponly cookies in php?

Tags: javascript, php, http, cookies

I'm doing a project where I need to use php-made cookies managing for managing some content.

However, when I make my cookies like this in php:

```php
$cookie_value = $user['username'];
setcookie('currentUser', $cookie_value);
```

And in another file on the site, I attempt to acces the cookie like this in javascript:

```js
var cookieArr = document.cookie.split(";");
```

Then I cannot access the cookie I just made, even though I can see in the in the browser developer tool, that the cookie exists.
I can read here on stacked overflow that it probably has something to do with my cookie being httponly, but I can't seem to find any answer on how I can create my cookie differently in php?

Many thanks for helping out

Comment: The default for the httponly option is FALSE.  See the documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).  So your code is not currently setting it to TRUE.  The problem is likely something else.  What specifically brought you to the conclusion that the problem was the httponly setting?

Comment: I found some stackoverflow questions with related issues. and they were told that it was probably that, but provided no soolution.

Comment: what else could it be?

Comment: @s3j80 Start with some simple debugging. What does `console.log(document.cookie)` show?

Comment: it shows 2 of the cookies on the site, but leaves out 2 other cookies, including the one i made myself

Comment: @s3j80  Try setting the path parameter to `"/"`.

Comment: omg, if thats the issue im gonna slap myself

Comment: i worked. Feeling so dumb right now, i actually deleted that argument earlier because i thought it was redundant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you haven't specified the `PATH`,

**Try this method,**

```
setcookie("currentUser", $cookie_value, time()+86400, "/");
```

**time()+86400 = Expire in 1 Day (You can change it)**